# Azure login to user db with pyodbc from a Azure webjob

Tags: pyodbc, azure-webjobs, azure-sql-server

I am trying to login to Azure sql server with pyodbc which logs me in a master db rather than the userdb like 'xyzdb' that i provide in the connection string. The solution to this seems changing to a DSN less based logins that needs configuring the dsn on windows machine.
But i require to run the python script with pyodbc connection from a Azure webjob so configuring dsn is not possible. Hence not able to use the user database as intended. Any solution?
After login to master db i thought to change to user db with "USE xyzdb;" Sql command to which the azure sql server responded 'USE cannot be used to switch between databases' hence xyzdb login cannot be made. I am stuck :).

Comment: What's your connection string? I can connect to my custom db, both in local and webjob.

Answer (score 0):

I made the azure sql server with xyzdb database. Then i tried connection string for newly created server:
pyodbc.connect('Driver={ ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server};Server=tcp:abc.database.windows.net,1433;Database=xyzdb;
Uid=ur_username;Pwd=ur_password;Encrypt=yes;TrustServerCertificate=no;Connection Timeout=30;')

This connection string logged me in masterdb not in xyzdb as intended. And As Sql server are physically maintained in stack in data center interconnection is not everytime feasible unless using something as pool elastic. So 'USE xyzdb;' Sql statement from master DB was providing 'USE cannot be used for switching between databases'.

for 3 days i tried with other methods but it didn't worked,so i posted the question.Then i tried the connection string as:

pyodbc.connect('Driver={ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server};Server=tcp:abc.database.windows.net,1433;
Uid=ur_username;Pwd=ur_password;Encrypt=yes;TrustServerCertificate=no;Connection Timeout=30;Database=xyzdb')

moving the Database field at the end of the string thinking it will first make a connection with server then it will log me in database xyzdb and It logged me in the xyzdb database.It worked the first time itself.

Now if i try with any of the 2 strings above its working as expected. Don't know what was the issue?.Looks like i wasted time of others as well :). we can remove the question i presume, as i can login the userdb. Thanks.